# Python - Steam User Status

Tags: python, steam

I've been looking for a method to get a steam users status. This includes things like the game they're playing, if they're online or if they're offline. I was originally going to scrape the page, but I figured there must be an easier way to do it.

I looked around for pages which might be json of the users current status, perhaps even an API. But I haven't found anything yet.

Answer (score 3):

Start with the [Steam Web API](http://steamcommunity.com/dev). I think you are looking to work with [GetPlayerSummaries](http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetPlayerSummaries_.28v0002.29).

Answer (score 1):

Did you see:

http://steamcommunity.com/dev

> Steam Web API Documentation
>
> Valve provides these APIs so website developers can use data from
>   Steam in new and interesting ways. They allow developers to query
>   Steam for information that they can present on their own sites. At the
>   moment the only APIs we offer provide item data for Team Fortress 2,
>   but this list will grow over time.